# How to use WSDL SOAP functions and objects in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, soap, wsdl

I just had a brief look at the Magento 2 WSDL file.

Until 1.9 I used the WSDL file as part of my development (Delphi win 32) to have access to the functions, arrays, objects etc... 
This was very helpful.

I already found the functions again... totally different names though, so I have to redevelop everything... which is time-consuming, but possible.

But what I haven't understood until now is the login credentials with the token system. In V1.9 I had an API-User and the corresponding password, 
which I could use to get my session ID: 
e.g. mage.login(myLoginParam)

I already found the extension settings in the Magento backend. 
But I really don't have a clue how to submit those consumer key, secrets... etc.. 
I am connecting to Magento using the HTTPRIO component from Delphi.

Can anyone enlighten me?

b/r
Holger

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SOAP Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/soap/bk-soap.html
Magento 2 have [api functional](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/dev/tests/api-functional) tests, they use also sSOAP to testing work with all APIs

Comment: Thanks for the hints, though its not answering any of my questions. I already new the link for the list of service endpoints... But i need a hint on how to use the consumer and access token and secrets. I dont have a clue how to use them in the connection method i mentioned above.

Comment: please see documentation about  [authentication](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html)

Comment: also see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459637/consuming-web-service-with-authentication-allways-give-message-authentication-re

Answer (score 0):

Example For PHP SOAP Client CALL For Magento 2 : 
Change your magento path , service name and accecs tocken in place of key after word 'Barear'

```
$request = new SoapClient(
    'http://magento2.ce/index.php/soap/? wsdl&services=foggylineSliderSlideRepositoryV1',
    array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer pk8h93nq9cevaw55bohkjbp0o7kpl4d3')
        ))
    )
);
$response = $request-> foggylineSliderSlideRepositoryV1GetById(array('slideId'=>1));
```

If you magento 2 with having order in database than this will shows you detail of order having id 1 because **salesOrderRepositoryV1** is default api provided by magento 2 , for more default apis : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/soap/bk-soap.html

```
$request = new SoapClient(
    'http://192.168.0.54/magento20sample/index.php/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1',
    array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
            'http'=> array('header' => 'Authorization: Bearer w9vqx2uyenkbvbim6mwochwapq714yox')
        ))
    )
);
$response = $request->SalesOrderRepositoryV1Get(array('id' => 1));
```

hope this will help you ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample file changing your credentials and the request URL.

```
<?php
$request = new SoapClient("http://magento.m2/index.php/soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1", array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));
$token = $request->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken(array("username"=>"admin", "password"=>"GN2vKgfsszz43u"));

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.json_decode($token->result)
    )
);

$wsdlUrl = 'http://magento.m2/soap/default?wsdl&services=directoryCurrencyInformationAcquirerV1';
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient(
    $wsdlUrl,
    array('version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context])
);

$soapResponse = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
```